# using mget for directory tree

Tags: linux, ftp, mget

How can I make one mget of one directory tree?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) does what you want...

Ftp itself does not support tree traversing

Answer (score 2):

Try `help mirror` in [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/), it does what you want, too.